# Android install .apk file programmatically

Tags: android, xamarin, installation, apk

I'm trying to do an autoupdate function, after a lot of search I've found solution for download .apk file from my server to my device
But i'can't launch this file, window to prompt user for install open but close direct.

this is my code

```
Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(destination);

Android.Net.Uri apkURI = Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(
                                  _context,
                                  _context.ApplicationContext.PackageName + ".provider", file);

 Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
 //promptInstall.SetDataAndType(apkURI, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
 promptInstall.SetData(apkURI);

 promptInstall.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
 promptInstall.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
         _context.GrantUriPermission(_context.ApplicationContext.PackageName, apkURI, ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
_context.StartActivity(promptInstall);
```

I've tryed with a lot of combinaison of flags and Ident.Action like ActionInstallPackage

android version is 8.1

thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve that?

Answer (score 9):

I have wrote a code in [java](/questions/tagged/java) with respect to `Uri` access exposure for `targetSdkVersion >= 24`, please try it in [xamarin](/questions/tagged/xamarin) yourself.

**ApkInstaller.java**

```
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;

public class ApkInstaller {

    public static void installApplication(Context context, String filePath) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uriFromFile(context, new File(filePath)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        try {
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("TAG", "Error in opening the file!");
        }
    }

    private static Uri uriFromFile(Context context, File file) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
        } else {
            return Uri.fromFile(file);
        }
    }

}
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="package.identifier">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application ... >

        ...

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**res/xml/provider_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

## Usage:

```
ApkInstaller.installApplication(context, filePath);
```

Comment: @r2b2s: Have you tested it?

Comment: thanks, but i've already tested this solution, and it's not wotking for me the apk installer windows is launched but immediatly closed... I've scrapped the idea and tried something new, use google play store with tested version

Comment: are u test it in android >Oreo?

Comment: @roghayehhosseini: I've tested it on Android `N`, as the problem comes from `N` and later, I think it is OK on `O`.

Comment: @aminography For me it showing  dialog `There was a problem while parsing the package` and security exception for `androidx.core.content.FileProvider` I have added `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` flag also

Answer (score 3):

**STEP-1**

First Create **xml** file inside your res/xml/provider_paths.xml 
and then

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="files_root"
        path="Android/data/${applicationId}" />
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

**STEP-2**

Add this in **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>

<application>
 <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
    </application>
```

**STEP-3 Final step**

Add this in your **Activity**  class

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                                    context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", new File(apkFilePath));
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                            startActivity(intent);

                        } else {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setDataAndType(FileUtils.getFileToUri(BaseActivity.this, new File(apkFilePath)),
                                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
```

**Note:** FileProvider only for Android >= Nougat

Using FileProvider you can get other **.extension** file like capture image **uri**

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", new File(imageFilePath));
```